# How to click a input tag within php form tag using cucumber

Tags: php, cucumber

```
<FORM METHOD=POST  NAME="WMLogon" ACTION=<?php echo "$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?s=$s&t=$t"; ?>
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="current_page" value=0>
    <table class="bar-status" width="70%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
    <td class="bar-search" align="center" bgcolor="#cddeff">
    <input tabindex="102" type="Submit"  name="Login" align="top" border="0" value="Login"/> </td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
</FORM>
```

i want to click on login button how can i do that please help me.......
i am not able to do this by using following code

```
Then /^I enter login details and press login button/ do
   fill_in "AUTH_USER", :with => "wmmpw@localhost"
   fill_in "AUTH_PW", :with => "wmmpw"
   click_button("Login")
end
```

Comment: Can you show your Cucumber step definition

Comment: here it is don't worry abt AUTH_USER and AUTH_PW i just want how click that form input tag.... please help me....

Comment: That's odd. The click_button command should be working.  I take it you have Capybara installed alongside Cucumber?

Comment: ha capybara is already installed.....

Comment: Are you getting any errors from Cucumber/Capybara, if so what are they?

Comment: Then I enter login details and press login button # features/step_definitions/testing.rb:17
      Could not find button "Login" (Webrat::NotFoundError)
      ./features/step_definitions/testing.rb:20:in `/^I enter login details and press login button/'
      features/testing.feature:10:in `Then I enter login details and press login button' this is what i'm getting as error....

Comment: if i change input type to button it ll work but i don't want change the existing code.....

Answer (score 0):

If you say it has to be an automated click then you have to go for javascript.

Just include this code after form.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.WMLogon.submit();
</script>
```

** One more thing, you didn't close form in line 1

```
<FORM METHOD=POST  NAME="WMLogon" ACTION=<?php echo "$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?s=$s&t=$t"; ?>  >
```

Comment: its working fine but i'm testing this code using cucumber i want to click login button using cucumber how can i do that..???

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a PHP/Cucumber env set up right now to check this, but I think you may need to add an `id` attribute to your submit button and use that in your step definition.

At the moment, Webrat can't find the button you are trying to click.

Comment: i hv used it with capybara also, when i used with capybara the visit command is not going to work.....